# How to use less memory when loading a large database using SqlAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, etl

I'm using SqlAlchemy to load some larg'ish datasets into a MySQL database. It has around a million rows and counting (~380 MB database size). I need to load this database into a pandas dataframe and for this I'm using code like this:

```
table_query = db_conn.Session.query(TableClass).yield_per(10000)
df = pd.read_sql(table_query.statement, table_query.session.bind)
```

where db_conn is defined using a connection string for the database and `TableClass` ORM object for that table and session defined as `db_conn.Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)`.

When I run this my server RAM is usage goes up to almost 6.5 GB. Which is strange because of the actual table isn't that big. As the database grows everyday the this will soon totally fill up the 8GB RAM in the machine.

What can I do to prevent this huge memory usage problem? One thing I did was use the `yield_for` to get the data in chunks but this did not help much at all.

Comment: So, after the table is done loading, the memory usage goes down to reasonable amounts? What sort of data are you working with? Can you print out the output of df.dtypes? My experience with loading data from sql is that there is a large chunk of memory needed because there is an intermediate step that involves moving the sql tables into python data structures which are memory heavy.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga there are around 50 columns typically so will be a bit long to print in the question i think. it's combination of dates, strings (max varchar(255) but not long texts), numeric integers and floating points etc. yes, the memory goes down back after the table is loaded.

Comment: Well, this will slow you down no doubt, but you might want to iterate over the `cursor.fetchall()`, or accumulate that in batches by taking some chunk, and manually append to the DataFrame. EDIT: not actually sure how `mysql` cursor's work, but you should be able to find one that let's you lazily iterate over the results of the query.

Comment: Please take a read of [How to Use SQLAlchemy Magic to Cut Peak Memory and Server Costs in Half](http://dev.mobify.com/blog/sqlalchemy-memory-magic/)

Comment: Hi @sfactor , did you ever manage to find out the answer to your question?